# Visual Studio Community 2015 Sign In Button Closes Everything

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have this Visual Studio 14.0 {Community 2015}. It was working fine besides my Visual Studio 2012. Someone recommended me to update it so I downloaded Visual Studio Update 2or3 I guess, the file is **vstf_testagent.exe**.

I updated, and then I started VS and the window pops up and says sign in, when I click Sign-In it Closes All Visual Studio Windows.
This is the error picture:

[image]

and when I click sign in vs starts like this...

[image]

once I click Sign In everything is gone !!!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you filed a report? https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: That file does not look like an update installer.

Comment: It Is An Update Installer i downloaded it myself from microsoft Site, and i think it really is a bug. suggest me a solution Guys i need it .